# Как сделать локальную переменную глобальной?

Tags: javascript

```js
function f1() {
  var a = 5;
  var b = 5;
  var c = a + b;

}

document.write(c);
```

Как вывести на экран переменную `c`? Я читал о замыканиях, пробовал `window` и просто объявлять переменную без слова `var` но не получилось.

Comment: Зачем? Нужно возвращать значение и использовать его.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно не делать из локальной глобальную, а возвращать из функции значение.

```js
function f1() {
  var a = 5;
  var b = 5;
  var c = a + b;
  return c;

}
var d = f1();
document.write(d);
```

Comment: почему `var`, а не `let` ?

Comment: @Serhii не знаю, можно и let. Просто скопировал, что было :)

Comment: с приходом ES2015 `var` уже не используется, вместо него `let` и `const`.